# How do I make case insensitive parameters in Akka http?

Tags: scala, akka-http

For example I have a directive:

```
val sourceTypeDirective: Directive1[DocumentSource] = {
parameters('docsource.as[String]) flatMap {
  case docSource if sourceAcceptedType(docSource) => provide(sourceValueOf(docSource))
  case _                                          => reject
  }
}
```

I want to get docsource even if it will be written as DOCSOURCE or DocSource, how can I make that?

Answer (score 1):

**No Direct Solution**

I don't think this is possible with the `parameters` Directive directly.  The `'docsource` Symbol is being converted into a `NameReceptacle` via [an implicit conversion method in `ParameterDirectives`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/server/directives/ParameterDirectives.html#_symbol2NR(symbol:Symbol):akka.http.scaladsl.common.NameReceptacle[String]).  There is only 1 `String` member variable in NameReceptacle: `name`.  This prevents any sort of regular expression matching or converting the Symbol into multiple Strings to match all possible capitalization patterns...

**Indirect Solution**

The [`parameterMap`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameterMap.html) Directive can be used to get a `Map[String, String]` where you can then operate on the keys:

```
val sourceTypeDirective : Directive1[DocumentSource] = 
  parameterMap { 
    (_ : Map[String, String])
      .view
      .map(tup => (tup._1.toLowerCase, tup._2))
      .toMap
      .get("docsource")
      .filter(sourceAcceptedType)
      .map(docSource => provide(sourceValueOf(docSource)))
      .getOrElse(reject)
  }
```

**Warning**

The query string key `"field"` is distinct from the key `"FIELD"`.  Those are technically 2 different keys and should correspond to 2 different values.  But any solution to the question would result in a key collision for those two fields.